# How to hide soft keyboard after selecting an item from recyclerview?

Tags: android

I have an edittext with recyclerview where a list of places will be displayed on searching.On clicking any item from list, the keyboard should hide. Please help

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to hide the keyboard inside `onClick()` of Item.

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
       InputMethodManager imm = 
       (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
       imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

call this method when clicked in searched list click

```
void hideKeybord() {
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its partially working. But again when i click on edittext  and edit the value, keyboard is closed.

Comment: so you want like when you touch or click on recycler view keyboard must ne hidden..right?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** Simply set an `onTouchListener()` to your `RecyclerView` and hide your keyboard:

```
yourRecycleView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        input.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

        return false;
    }
});
```

Hope this will come in handy.

Comment: @Elackya Are you getting any error? Try to write "return true;" at the end

Comment: I dont get any error, keyboard doesn't hide after click event

Comment: Can you post your code, where you have tried something. @Elackya

Comment: @Elackya Good.. Can you post your code as an answer so that others can know too.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this - call this method inside the onClick of recycler ViewHolder

```
public void hideKeyboard(){
                edittext.clearFocus()
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)
                if (imm != null) {
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.windowToken, 0)
                }
    }
```